# add tables dynamically based on database schema

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, dataset

I have a DataSet to which I need to add tables dynamically at runtime, but these tables need to reflect the existing database structures.  Is there a way to pull the schema (not data) of a specific table into a DataSet at runtime.

So, for instance, I might have an Account table (along with hundreds of others) in a database.  I need to create an Account table in the DataSet at runtime (based on various actions of the end users) but there are too many to manually code this for each table.

Comment: Why don't you just use Entity Framework? Then you can reference each table as an object and use some logic to determine which is needed.

Comment: Use an 
SqlCommand
with text
"select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'tableName'"

do anything you want with the data reader..

Comment: @VenkatRenukaPrasad No need to query the DB, he can do that programatically since he has the DataSet object, he can look into it and traverse the schema. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify wich database engine you were working on, so the best generic method to do what you want to do would be to use IDataReader's GetSchemaTable method.

More info on how to do this [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310108).

Answer (score 0):

If you run a SQL query that returns a datatable, it will have the structure of the table.  Thus,

```
select * from SourceTable where 1 = 2;
```

Which returns no rows, but all the columns.  DataSet fill, etc.  Done.

Answer (score 0):

You can programatically modify and examine your data schema and data. You can add Columns programatically to the DataSet: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfx3s9wd.aspx

```
DataTable workTable = new DataTable("Customers");

DataColumn workCol = workTable.Columns.Add("CustID", typeof(Int32));
workCol.AllowDBNull = false;
workCol.Unique = true;

workTable.Columns.Add("CustLName", typeof(String));
workTable.Columns.Add("CustFName", typeof(String));
workTable.Columns.Add("Purchases", typeof(Double));
```

You can create new tables also into the DataSet. You can examine and traverse the schema of what you have: look at the Tables property of DataSet, it contains your DataTables (DataTableCollection). The DataTables contain Columns property. Knowing that it's straight forward.